# Why flip qx, qy, qz in Quaternion by its w value?

Tags: flip, quaternions

if we let bquat = w + qx * i + qy * j+ qz * k, where i, j k are sqrt(-1)
can anyone tell me, why after we normalize Quaternion,
we need to further flip the qx, qy,qz if qw > 0 ???

```
bquat = self.matrix.to_quaternion()
bquat.normalize()
qx = bquat.x
qy = bquat.y
qz = bquat.z
if bquat.w > 0:
    qx = -qx
    qy = -qy
    qz = -qz
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the context? It is probably about "taking the short way around" which usually means flipping if w is negative. The short way is probably positive due to the starting orientation being negative in your case. Need some details. It is not because you normalized, but because of whatever operation caused you to not be normalized to begin with.

Comment: I found that the MD5 export Blender python script export the quaternion in that way.  When restoring, the Android java code will also need to compute the w value:
t = 1 - (qx*qx + qy * qy + qz * qz);
if (t < 0) {w = 0;} else {w = -sqrt(t);} -- [1]
In my Blender python export script, I didn't flip qx, qy,qz with respect to w value when exporting restpose and posture of all bones.  I found that I need  to compute w value by [1].
Even though, my animation still come out with some distortion in it when playing.  Why?